# Containing element not expanding vertically when content has rotated text

Tags: html, css

I have a table with some th tags that contain text that is rotated via CSS.  The problem I have is that the th is not expanding vertically with the content.  Here is a basic example of the markup I have:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>
            <div class="rotated-text">Some Text</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="rotated-text">Some More Text</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="rotated-text">Even More Text</div>
        </th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.rotated-text {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UPFkX/1/

Comment: You should also include `-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);`

Comment: Yes I know. The example CSS is just to provide a basic example of the issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few edits to your code.

Remove the `div` and add the `class"rotated-text"` to your `th`.
add this javascript
     `$(".verticalTableHeader").each(function(){$(this).height($(this).width())})`

Make sure your page calls on jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/UPFkX/3/

Comment: Brilliant, it works. However, the width of the table headers is now the same value as the height of content.  I want all of the headers to display as, say, 28px wide.

Comment: You can add some padding to the heading like so `th {padding: 5px;}` this will make the width 30px. Now if you add padding like so `padding: 1px 2px 3px 4px` it now starts from the left and moves cw.

Comment: What I meant was that rotating the text via css transform makes the element visually rotated, however it still occupies the same space as if it had not been. This causes the table headers to take as much space as if they weren't rotated when visually, they are all as wide as the line-height of the text. Here is an example to demonstrate what I mean: jsfiddle.net/UPFkX/6

Answer (score 7):

The containing elements can not expand, as css transformations (and IE filters) do not influence the [box model](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/).

To qoute Marco Miltenburg:

> If I'm not mistaken elements are part of the normal flow or are
>   floated as if they are not transformed. Once their position has been
>   established, then the transformation or transition is performed. The
>   transformation or transition will not have any influence on the
>   document flow or any floating anymore.

You can find his answer to a similar question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860413/css3-transform-for-text-rotate).

Actually, the `width` property of the transformed element will actually change it's visible "height" now, and the `height` property will change it's visible "width". In short:

**With css transformations, it's the apperance that's being transformed, not the element itself or it's "influence" on the document flow.**

What might help you though (case dependent):

Set the `height` property of each transformed element to it's `width` in pixels. That will influence their containers height just the way you want it.

**EDIT:**

As Juan Rangel said in his answer, you could go for javascript to solve the problem. I totally agree on that - what he would do with jquery is the same thing I was talking about above. If you can not tell how tall the transformed elements will be, that might even be the better solution, but keep the (small amout of) clients in mind that don't allow you to use javascript.
Anyways, you'll have to compromise unfortunately.