# One Bootstrap column with vertical text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to put "VERTICAL_TEXT" (third bootstrap column) with 90º rotation.
I have tried the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color: yellow;">
        <span>FOO1</span><br/>
        <span>FOO2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8" style="background-color: red;">
        <div>
            <span>BAR1</span><br/>
            <span>BAR2</span><br/>
            <span>BAR3</span><br/>
            <span>BAR4</span><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color: blue;">
            <span class="rotate_text">VERTICAL TEXT</span>
    </div>
</div>



.text_rotate {
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);

    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);

    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);

    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);

    /* Internet Explorer */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

The following fiddle ilustrates the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/fbtg1zjx/

---

Edited:

I included the inline-block style and the text is now rotated as suggested in answers, however the text does not start in the upper part of the document. (the whole text includes 4 characters before N/00001. In green it is the span item, in blue the parent div.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Containing element not expanding vertically when content has rotated text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712981/containing-element-not-expanding-vertically-when-content-has-rotated-text)

Answer (score 1):

Many CSS rules including Width, Height and such transforms doesn't work on elements with display:inline, an span is by default an inline elemnt, just give it a display:block or inline-block and it should work for you.. 
also try to add a general transform rule , transform:rotate(90deg);

to fix the second issue where the text is outside of the container you can use following CSS fixes :

```
.text_rotate { 
    /* add  translate(50%) to transforms */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(50%); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(50%); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(50%); 
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(50%); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); 
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(50%);
    display:block; 
}
```

or use transform origin

```
.text_rotate {  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); 
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    display:block; 
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}
```

Please test and see which one is better for your situation.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You should put the `text_rotate` on the parent div.